# adding an existing project from one collection to another project from another collection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I need to be able to add an existing project from one collection, to another project from another collection

But when i do this in visual studio (by clicking on Add->Existing Project then selecting the project which has already been checked into another collection and sits on my local drive)
I get the error message:

"The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized. Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings"

When i open the project that's in the different collection standalone, it works fine (and source control is mapped)

Not sure if this is possible, but it should be (seems a bit silly that it wouldn't be supported)

Comment: So are you trying to have the same project stored under multiple source control project collections?

Comment: It's not possible. Team Project Collections cannot relate to each other. That's sort of the point. See "Disadvantages" under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd236915.aspx.

Comment: but what if you have teams collections like "web team" and "business systems team" and i want to import an existing business systems project to a web project so i dont have duplicated code all over the place - doesnt seem logical to me that this wouldn't be supported